# Write file at a specific value and line

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file, text

I want to write data at a specified value in a text file from a text box. Here is a example:

`item_begin etcitem 3344 item_type=etcitem` is first line and `item_begin weapon 3343 item_type=weapon` is second. Well i want to replace `item_type=weapon` at second line with `item_type=armor`. Here is code so far:

```
var data2 = File.WriteAllLines("itemdata.txt")
    .Where(x => x.Contains("3343"))
    .Take(1)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Split('\t'))
    .Select(x => x.Split('='))
    .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1]);
```

But returns error at WriteAllLines.
Here is the readline part code:

```
var data = File.ReadLines("itemdata.txt")
    .Where(x => x.Contains("3343"))
    .Take(1)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Split('\t'))
    .Select(x => x.Split('='))
    .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1]);
//call values

textitem_type.Text = data["item_type"];
```

And want to write the same value I change on `textitem_type.Text` after read.

I used this to reaplace but replaces all values with same name from line and returns me in text only 1 line. Code:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var data = File
                    .ReadLines("itemdata.txt")
                    .Where(x => x.Contains(itemSrchtxt.Text))
                    .Take(1)
                    .SelectMany(x => x.Split('\t'))
                    .Select(x => x.Split('='))
                    .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
                    .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1]);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\itemdata.txt");
        string content = reader.ReadLine();
        reader.Close();
        content = Regex.Replace(content, data["item_type"], textitem_type.Text);
          StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\itemdata.txt");
        write.WriteLine(content);
        write.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try Replace the **WriteAllLines** to **ReadAllLines**

```
var data2 = File.ReadAllLines("itemdata.txt");

//use linq if you want, it just an example fo understandin
Foreach (var dataline in data2 ) 
{
   if (dataline.Contains("3343"))
       dataline = "item_begin weapon 3343 item_type=weapon" //of course you can use the split, it just an example
}

File.WriteAllLines("itemdata.txt", data2);
```

Comment: i update too, maybe it can help with simple logic of read and write. And please visit the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693.aspx page for understand WriteAll method

Comment: Changing the value of dataline in the loop won't change the contents of the array.

Comment: The problem is line contains more sections with name `weapon` and if i used that it replaces all parts with name weapon.